# Why won't this 3/8 male connector for a natural gas dryer fit a 3/8 female connector?

Tags: dryer, natural-gas, propane

First off, I changed the Natural Gas orifice to a factory ordered LP orifice, I am not just trying to hook up a LP line to a natural gas dryer without setting the dryer up correctly for LP.

My problem is that the female end LP line, professionally installed, does not fit my dryer male connection.

The fitting is so close, it feels like it will thread but just doesn't.

I am seeing stuff online [about a flare end to a threaded end](http://ths.gardenweb.com/forums/load/laundry/msg071956059283.html?6)

Is there anything I am doing wrong, or is my dryer female not the 3/8" I am thinking it is?

The instructions for my dryer says it is 3/8":
[image]

I added some images to assist with my question:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I had the **exact** situation on my new LG Gas dryer & found this thread. There are 2 things I found at play making it hard to thread the adapter onto the dryer (once you have an adapter). The black coating on the pipe + the nature of the tapered threads. These 2 in combination made it seem really uncomfortable screwing on the proper 3/8" adapter. Using a wrench & pipe dope on the _outside_ threads did work. I'll note it doesn't screw all the way on the threads. It stopped about 1/2 way because of the taper & black coating. If I had tightened more I would have bent the pipe or broken something

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a 3/8" female NPT x 3/8" male flare thread adapter. Any good hardware store or plumbing shop.

[image]

Comment: Do think this braided steel cable compared to a corrugated steel pipe is an issue, I am living in Mexico and this what the professional installed

Comment: Check to see if it is labeled for indoor use with LPG and see if it has other industry group certifications. I have seen many LPG connectors that are braided stainless steel with an internal liner.

Comment: Just to add, Ace Hardware is really good for having these sorts of items in stock. I just read this thread and bought a 1/2" to 1"2 adapter (for my particular job) from them today. The big box stores don't seem to carry individual ones as much, and they must be ordered.

Comment: You need an adapter that goes from NPT to flare. And the female may not be 3/8'' it may be 1/2'' and then you just need a NPT 3/8 to flare 1/2.

Comment: Used this adapter for the gas line of the back of a Samsung Gas dryer Model DVG45R6100C/a3. Works great. B&K 3/8-in Threaded Flare x FIP Adapter Coupling Fitting
Item #877028Model #FL-176B. Bought at Lowes.

Answer (score 4):

The short pipe you show is a section of tapered NPT black iron pipe.

As a sidenote, there should not be pipe dope inside the pipe, the dope should only be on the threads.

The section of corrugated pipe is most likely designed to connect to a flared pipe with straight threads. The required two adapters should have been sold with the pipe because it has to be matched to the particular flare shape in order to make a leak-proof connection. Pipe dope should NOT be applied to the threads of the flare connection. If you don't have them, but a new corrugated pipe with the required adapters.

You may have damaged the existing threads by using the wrong connection. It would be best if all possibly damaged sections of pipe are replaced with new pipe.

Also, the style of pipe you show is not the type of pipe I'm familiar with in the USA for gas piping. I use single-walled corrugated steel pipe, not pipe with braided stainless steel like you've shown. What you show is more similar to what I'd expect for tubes in outside temporary LP applications.

As always, the connections should be leak-checked after assembly.

Comment: Why do you think the threads are damaged, I never threaded the  female braided stainless steel to the dryer tapered NPT black iron pipe. I didn't force it, I just tried to attach it and saw that it would not attach.

Comment: Oh I see, you are suggesting that I may have damaged the threads, no I am quite sure the threads are fine I never forced the connection in anyway.

Comment: Right, I was worried about "The fitting is so close, it feels like it will thread but just doesn't." meaning that you threaded it on somewhat (along with the photograph of the great big wrench). If you used minimal force, it's probably fine.

Comment: Do think this braided steel cable compared to a corrugated steel pipe is an issue, I am living in Mexico and this what the professional installed

Comment: The steel pipe is good. It's the flexible pipe that I would be concerned about.

Comment: OK thanks, I purchasing a corrugated steel pipe to replace the flexible pipe

Comment: So I am living in Mexico and they only had for sale the flexible pipe for gas. So that picture in my original question is definitely a gas line, just wanted to share with you

Comment: Different countries, different allowed products. For example, [this product on Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/BrassCraft-PSC1081-K5-Safety-Installation/dp/B000BPHMFK) is the sort of connector we use in the US.

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the same issue with a new dryer.  The normal adapter did not want to screw onto the pipe thread coming out of the back of the dryer.

Having worked with plumbing for many years something just did not look right about the threads on the pipe coming out of the dryer.  I carefully measured the thread depth with a special caliper.  Sure enough the threads were not cut deep enough.  The number of threads per inch was proper so I used a pipe die and cut the threads to the proper depth.  BINGO, the adapter fit just the way it should and the new dryer is working properly.

I have elected to not mention the brand of the dryer but it is my understanding that many different brands use parts made by the same supplier.  SHAME on the supplier for such POOR Quality Control.  Buyer BEWARE!!